# How to get two different fields with the same name in a Response API using Rest Assured?

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I'm trying to create a Test Automation for a GET API using Rest-Assured and Java.

This API has the follow response body:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "3185",
            "customer_id": "299",
            "region": "São Paulo",
            "region_id": 1234,
            "country_id": "BR",
            "street": [
                "Av Paulista"
            ],
            "company": "Teste",
            "telephone": "(19) 99999-9999",
            "postcode": "",
            "city": "Valinhos",
            "firstname": "N/A",
            "lastname": "N/A",
            "middlename": null,
            "prefix": null,
            "suffix": null,
            "person_type": "PF",
            "document": "43448871703",
            "state_registry": null,
            "created_at": "2019-07-24 13:03:29"
        },
        {
            "id": "3188",
            "customer_id": "299",
            "region": "São Paulo",
            "region_id": 1234,
            "country_id": "BR",
            "street": [
                "Av Paulista"
            ],
            "company": "Teste",
            "telephone": "(19) 99999-9999",
            "postcode": "",
            "city": "Valinhos",
            "firstname": "N/A",
            "lastname": "N/A",
            "middlename": null,
            "prefix": null,
            "suffix": null,
            "person_type": "PJ",
            "document": "84047942000115",
            "state_registry": null,
            "created_at": "2019-07-24 13:03:30"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this API response there is two fields with the same name "id". How can I get the value of these two fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this article: https://techeplanet.com/parse-json-array-using-rest-assured/

```java
    @Test
    public void verifyJSONArrayResponse() {
        JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();

        jsonArray = given().baseUri("http://<your host>")
                .basePath("<your path>")
                .get().as(JsonArray.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = jsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            System.out.println(jsonObject.get("id").getAsString());
        }
    }
```

You'll need to adjust it a bit though, to extract `items` first (your array) from a top-level response object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily by using JsonPath: `$.items[*].id` this will give you both the ids.

Comment: This will work only if you're using Jayway's json-path (https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) and not rest-assured's json-path implementation (https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-using-jsonpath) which the OP is using. As specified in the docs, rest-assured used Groovy GPath (http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath) syntax for its json-path.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using REST-assured, you can extract what you want directly from the response itself like so:

```
List<Integer> = given()
                  .spec(yourRequestSpecification)
                  .get("/your_api_endpoint") // returns Response
                  .then()                    // returns ValidatableResponse
                  .extract()                 // returns ExtractableResponse
                  .path("items.id");         // Groovy GPath syntax
```

[Jayway's jsonpath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) and [REST-assured's jsonpath](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-using-jsonpath) use differing syntaxes

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code .

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import bsh.ParseException;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

public class KeyValueJsonArrayExample {

    @Test
    public void getResponseAsJsonArray() throws ParseException, JSONException {

        RequestSpecification myreq = RestAssured.given();

        Response MyRes;
        MyRes = myreq.get("http://localhost:3000/posts/");
        String jsonResponse = MyRes.asString();
        System.out.println("Full String is" + jsonResponse);

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            org.json.JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String value1 = jsonObject1.optString("id");
            String value2 = jsonObject1.optString("auhtor");
            String value3 = jsonObject1.optString("title");
            System.out.println("The values are" + value1 + value2 + value3);
        }

    }

}
```

Also if you need only need to get particular index , please try

```
Response response=given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).get("http://localhost:3000/posts");
        JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
        String title = jsonPathEvaluator.get("title[2]");
        String author=jsonPathEvaluator.get("author[2]");
```